# clickhouse data insertion through API

Tags: database, api, clickhouse

I can get data from the clickhouse database using get method,
Similarly i want to insert data using post method .
Is their anyway to do like that

Answer (score 3):

Modification of data in HTTP interface is allowed using POST method only.

Check out example given below on Clickhouse official documentation.

```
echo 'INSERT INTO t VALUES (1),(2),(3)' | curl 'http://localhost:8123/' --data-binary @-
```

https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/interfaces/http_interface/

Edit With Post Image.

[Screenshot of postman and clickhouse client after insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu8l4.png)

Comment: I can do this in terminal alone,
but i want to do this in postman.when try this in post man it say ," can't insert data in read only mode"
Thanks for the answer

Comment: I just tried with Postman. Make sure you have set method as POST.

Comment: could you please send me ur example,and tell me how to do that in postman

Comment: Hi, I have added PostMan Screenshot and Clickhouse data screenshot.

Comment: Happy I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
 Initially, change `<readonly>` Tag in user.xml of click house-server from read-only mode to read & write mode by changing `<readonly>` tag value to 0(zero).

Url:http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT%20INTO%20db_name.table_name%20FORMAT%20Values
Body: ('1','2','3') // Body should be in tuple format.

Refer:https://clickhouse-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/query_complexity.html#readonly