# Why is "Cannot modify setting in readonly mode" thrown when not explicitly modify it in ClickHouse?

Tags: settings, readonly, clickhouse

Applications were using readonly user when the following exception was thrown:

```
<Error> HTTPHandler: Code: 164, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot modify 'result_overflow_mode' setting in readonly mode
```

I read ClickHouse code and found that when query goes with `set setting`, if the user is read-only, this error will be thrown.

I checked the configuration of my read-only-user in `users.xml` and found that `max_result_rows/bytes` and `result_overflow_mode` were not actively set.

However, my query does not go with `set setting`.

So what logic triggers the change of this setting?

Comment: Please check the below answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52549395/2536745

Comment: you need https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/permissions_for_queries/#settings_readonly readonly mode 2 and http post

Comment: Thanks, guys! But I'm wondering what logic triggers the change of this `result_overflow_mode` setting cause I didn't do it explicitly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to specify `<readonly>2</readonly>`.

Description of `readonly` parameter: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/permissions_for_queries/#settings_readonly

> Possible values:
>   0 — All queries are allowed.
>   1 — Only read data queries are allowed.
>   2 — Read data and change settings queries are allowed.

So, with readonly=2 you are let to you client to set `result_overflow_mode` but dont let to execute inserts and other requests of modifying data.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very detailed. Do you have any idea about what logic may trigger the change of this `result_overflow_mode setting` cause I didn't do it explicitly.

Comment: In my case my client DBeaver sets `result_overflow_mode`